# Gridview1 will not update on postback

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with the below attributes

```
        AllowSorting="true"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        BorderStyle="None"
        CellPadding="3"
        CssClass="inboundTbl"
        EnableModelValidation="True"
        PageSize="2"
        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
        OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"
        Width="100%"
        >
```

and for some odd reason, it does not like to update when I tried someone's sort tutorial.  Well, this time I'm trying a filter tutorial and I'm really confused on the matter.

This is the templatefield in question.

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Terminal ID" SortExpression="VUCTID">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Terminal:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTerminal" runat="server"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="TerminalChanged"
                    >
                        <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Value="ALL"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("VUCTID") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I've asked for help on why it won't update and he said that the the GridView is populated dynamically, which causes the datatable to return null.  I'm not sure what that means, but I haven't heard from him since.  I'll post the functions to filter as well, just in case the problem lies there.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack){
            ViewState["Filter"]="ALL";
            BindGridView();
            lastUpdated.Text = "Load: " + DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

protected void BindGridView()
{
    string query = @"censored";
    using (iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(connect))
    {
        using (iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            iDB2DataAdapter da = new iDB2DataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            //iDB2DataReader reader;
            //reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.Horizontal;
            DropDownList ddlTerminal = (DropDownList)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ddlTerminal");
            this.BindTerminalList(ddlTerminal);

        }
    }
}

protected void TerminalChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlTerminal = (DropDownList)sender;
    ViewState["Filter"] = ddlTerminal.SelectedValue;
    this.BindGridView();
}

private void BindTerminalList(DropDownList ddlTerminal)
{
    string query = "censored";
    using (iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(connect))
    {
        using (iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            iDB2DataAdapter da = new iDB2DataAdapter();
            ddlTerminal.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddlTerminal.DataTextField = "VUCTID";
            ddlTerminal.DataValueField = "VUCTID";
            ddlTerminal.DataBind();
        }
        ddlTerminal.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["Filter"].ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ah I'm sorry.  By update I mean it wouldn't filter the gridview.  The dropdown box in the template will populate from the database and once clicked, the gridview should update and filter according to the selected dropdown item.  But when I click it, the page will load, but the gridview looks unaffected.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "won't update"?  I don't follow.  Are you trying to update data in a database, and that's not working?  Are you trying to change something at the client, in response to a PostBack, and that's not working?

Comment: If you throw a breakpoint in TerminalChanged() does it ever hit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the initial postback, Filter should be all:

```
 if(!IsPostBack){
   ViewState["Filter"]="ALL";
   BindGridView();
   lastUpdated.Text = "Load: " + DateTime.Now;
}
```

For other postbacks, Filter value should be set. The query should be updated accordingly.

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Terminal = '" + ViewState["Filter"] + "'";
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I've purposely left out the query to leave out unnecessary reading.  I happened to comment the if(!postback) on my last try to debug the problem, thinking it was a postback issue.

Comment: I asked for help on another forum and their answer, though more informative on their side, is like yours so I'm marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just remove the comment in “//if (!IsPostBack){” and “//}” and you will give your required output.

Check below code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack){
    ViewState["Filter"] = "ALL";
    BindGridView();
    lastUpdated.Text = "Load: " + DateTime.Now;
    }
}
protected void BindGridView()
{
    string query = @"";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("VUCTID");
    if(Convert.ToString(ViewState["Filter"])=="1")
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 1;
    }
    if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Filter"]) == "2")
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 2;
    }
    if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Filter"]) == "3")
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 3;
    }
    if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Filter"]) == "4")
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 4;
    }
    if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Filter"]) == "5")
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 5;
    }
    if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Filter"]) == "ALL")
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 1;
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 2;
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 3;
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 4;
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 5;
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.Horizontal;
    DropDownList ddlTerminal =   (DropDownList)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ddlTerminal");
    this.BindTerminalList(ddlTerminal);
}

protected void TerminalChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlTerminal = (DropDownList)sender;
    ViewState["Filter"] = ddlTerminal.SelectedValue.ToString();
    this.BindGridView();
}

private void BindTerminalList(DropDownList ddlTerminal)
{
    string query = "";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("VUCTID");

    dt.Rows.Add();
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 1;
    dt.Rows.Add();
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 2;
    dt.Rows.Add();
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 3;
    dt.Rows.Add();
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 4;
    dt.Rows.Add();
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["VUCTID"] = 5;
    ddlTerminal.DataSource = dt;
    ddlTerminal.DataTextField = "VUCTID";
    ddlTerminal.DataValueField = "VUCTID";
    ddlTerminal.DataBind();
    ddlTerminal.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["Filter"].ToString()).Selected = true;
}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

}
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: If your code is what I think it is, I don't think I can use it.  The number of rows will be different on every page load and to my experience, I've had trouble getting the correct length of the gridview.